# Setup of Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My objective is to automate scenarios which are web based using Selenium with Python.

Now I am not sure what are the pre-configuration required for this.

What I have done so far is

1. Download & Install latest version of Python from https://www.python.org/ for windows 64 bit
2. Added the path

C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

3. Installed selenium libraries using "pip install -U Selenium" from command promt
4. Downloaded PyCharm from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/
5. Downloaded Selenium Standalone Server version 3.13.0 from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

With all these setup when i try to execute below piece of code in pycharm I get error message

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

**Error Message:**

> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Am I missing something? 
I have gone through many articles, and every article has different explanations. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: you have to download chromeDriver first

Comment: What is your Python file called, does it happen to be selenium.py? Did you install selenium into the active virtual environment for your project (or is it all global)? You shouldn't need to update the path manually, the Python installer offers to do this for you, maybe that's a clue to what is going wrong? You also probably don't need the Selenium server for what you're trying to do, perhaps it's good to take a few steps back?

Answer (score 0):

Put chrome webdriver in your env PATH or put path in you init like blow

```
webdriver.chrome(executable_path='{your driver path}')
```

download address:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

you need to a webdriver (chrome driver) for chrome, for selenium to work upon
You can get the driver from this site
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/
unzip the folder it must contain the chromedriver.exe

while instantiation a driver object, provide the path for 
Ex: `driver = webdriver.chrome("Full File path of chromedriver")`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it was not working, and I had to do a workaround.

This is what I did and it works

1. Downloaded .gz file from https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#description
2. Extract it and place it under Python Lib folder. Attached is for your reference.
3. Add the Selenium folder path in environment variable.

Resolved the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS6RQ.png)
Thank you all for your suggestions.

Note: For some reason *pip install selenium* didnt install everything is what I think. probably that was the cause for it

Regards,
Sid